# ajax indicator before complete loading

Tags: ajax, loading

How can I display an ajax indicator before all the images within a website layout were loaded?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery.  Please.

```
    $("#loading").ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    });
    $("#loading").ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).addClass('ohmy').hide('slow');
    });
```